# OutOfMemory Error for IOUtils.toByteArray()

Tags: java, file, stream, out-of-memory, arrays

I am getting the OOM error at the below line in the code. Is there a way to resolve it? I tried increasing the heap size to no use.

```
FileInputStream inputDoc = new FileInputStream(inputDoc1);
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputDoc);

upl.edmsDocument = bytes;
```

**UPDATE:** Added the below arguments `-Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -Xincgc` Then Im able to upload few large files continuously, but the performance is not consistent.

Comment: Well, how big is the file?

Comment: Anything greater than 10MB fails. However if I send 5 files of 3MB each, no error.

Comment: Increase the heap or stream the data

Comment: Like I said, increasing the heap size doesnt work. How do I stream the data?

Comment: How much did you try to increase the heap size? Anyway, it all depends on what happens with the data after that. The basic rules is - process chunks of the data each time rather than reading it whole into memory.

Comment: I went up to 2g. Can you show me how to read chunks?

Comment: Works on my machine. I've tried reading a 40Mb file using `commons-io-1.4` on Java `1.4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, and `8` using 32-bit and 64-bit, and `commons-io-2.4` on Java `6`, `7`, and `8` using 32-bit and 64-bit. For 64-bit, it just worked. For 32-bit, I had to give `-Xmx1024m`, and then it worked fine. Test program was those first two lines, followed by a print of the array length.

Comment: Im using `commons-io-2.4` with Java `6` and 32-bit. I can send 100MB file as well, from my machine. But when I run this on the server, with same Java version and almost 4GB physical memory and `-Xmx2048m` , fails randomly with this error.

Comment: Exact Java version `1.6.0_35-b10`

Answer (score 1):

If you know the size of your input you should use `toByteArray(inputDoc1, inputDoc1Size)` instead of `toByteArray(inputDoc1)`. Be aware that you are limited by Integer.MAX_VALUE entries anyway as stated in [API documentation.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29)

Comment: Each input varies. How do I get the size of each file/

Comment: Tried this. Same issue.